# Select all row with the same ID in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
public function fetchDataPost($id){
    global $pdo;

    $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE idUsers = ?");
    $query->bindValue(1, $id);
    $query->execute();

    return $query->fetch();
}
```

Table: posts

| idPosts | idUsers | contentPosts | videoPosts | imagePosts | dateCreatedPosts |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | This is a post | NULL | NULL | 1624011593 |
| 2 | 1 | This is an another post | NULL | NULL | 1624017542 |

I want to get all the rows with the same idUsers value. To show the user's post in the profile page.

Comment: `return $query->fetchAll();` to get all rows `->fetch()` only gets the next row

Comment: ↑ This. I finally got it to work. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE idUsers = :id");
$query->bindValue(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

I assume that the value of the $id is an integer so I use PDO::PARAM_INT as third parameter.

you can learn about binding value here.

[PHP PDO bind value](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php)